# ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.6.4 and <3.8.0 but 3.8.3 was found instead

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am working on a Ionic Project which requires to have TypeScript 3.8.3 due to a plugin. It works well on my Windows PC, but when i try to compile it on a Mac i am getting the following error:

ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.6.4 and <3.8.0 but 3.8.3 was found instead.

Both Mac and Windows have the same Ionic and Angular versions.

What can i do to to correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Either upgrade your Angular version (Angular 12 supports TS 4.2) or set the angularCompilerOptions in tsconfig.json to allow unsupported versions of TypeScript:
https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#disabletypescriptversioncheck

Comment: How can I check what angular version I have on my Mac project?

Comment: Is this done using nodejs?

Comment: Look inside your package.json, all installed packages are listed there 

Comment: I have the following on both Windows and Mac
"@angular/cli": "9.0.6",

    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.6", ~

 It Seems on mac it not working with same compiler version

Comment: If you update all angular packages to 9.1.*, TS 3.8 is supported.

Comment: Thanks got it working on my mac, but still need to test the plugin

Is there a reason why 9.0.6 was working on my Windows, but Mac required 9.1?

Comment: Probably different TS actually installed (not necessarily same as in package.json when ^ is used) in the project if I am guessing